Fifteen boxes and two prizes
Andrew and Barbara are playing a game. Fifteen boxes are arranged in a 3-by-5 grid, labeled with the letters A through O, as shown below.

The organizers of the game have chosen two boxes randomly and placed a prize in each of the two chosen boxes. (It is the same prize in both boxes.) Andrew and Barbara each secretly submit to the organizers a search order, meaning the order in which they wish to examine the boxes. Andrew decides to search the boxes row by row, from left to right, top to bottom. His search order is therefore ABCDEFGHIJKLMNO. Barbara, however, decides to search the boxes column by column, from top to bottom, left to right. So her search order is AFKBGLCHMDINEJO.
After receiving the two search orders, the organizers now step through the two search orders in parallel. The first player to hit one of the prizes is declared the winner (ties are possible). For example, suppose that K and E happen to be the boxes with prizes in them. Then Barbara will hit the prize in box K on step 3, whereas Andrew won’t hit a prize until step 5, when he reaches box E, so Barbara wins in this case. For another example, suppose that the prizes are in boxes H and N. Then both Andrew and Barbara will hit the prize in box H on step 8, and the result will be a tie. For a third example, suppose that the prizes are in boxes E and G. Then Andrew will reach box E on step 5 and Barbara will reach box G on step 5, and again it will be a tie.

Question 1. Is  Is Andrew more likely to win this game, or is Barbara? Or are they equally likely to win?
Question 2. Does the answer change if there is only one prize instead of two?

Remark 1: The image is stolen from Gil Kalai's blog, where he recently posted this puzzle. I don't feel too bad about the theft, though, because the puzzle itself is original with me, and Kalai posted it on his blog at my request.
Remark 2: Some readers may be reminded of the bingo paradox. The bingo paradox is delightful, but the present puzzle is unrelated.

Is this not essentially the same as this question?

@JaapScherphuis Oh, you're right...I had forgotten that this had been posted here already! Should I close this because it's a duplicate?

Is there any intuition to be found here, why rot13(gur gjb nafjref qvssre)? I find this especially surprising since rot13(sbe bayl cevmr lbh pna fb rnfvyl frr gung gur punaprf ner gur fnzr ol ebgngvat nobhg gur U)

@TimSeifert It basically boils down to this: rot13(Gur obkrf Naqerj uvgf orsber Oneonen ner zber gbjneqf gur fgneg bs uvf frdhrapr pbzcnerq gb Oneonen'f obkrf va ure frdhrapr. Gung vf zbfgyl orpnhfr gur N unf n ybat eha ba gur gbc ebj svefg juvyr O ybfrf gvzr ybbcvat onpx gb gur gbc ebj gbb bsgra.
) Your observation does show why things are more as you would expect if there is only one prize.

@JaapScherphuis Ah, that actually makes a lot of sense. Thank you

@TimSeifert You got it already, but I forgot to add that rot13(gur cevmrf ner havsbezyl qvfgevohgrq bire gur frdhrapr, fb vs gurer vf zber guna bar cevmr gur svefg bar sbhaq vf ovnfrq gbjneqf gur ortvaavat bs gur frdhrapr, jurer N unf gur nqinagntr.)
